# Documentation routing example not fully working

Tags: angular, url-routing

I downloaded the example from the [Angular2 documentation on Routing and Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). It can be run live on [this plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html).

While the routing works in that clicking on the links navigates to the corresponding components and changes to url, navigating directly to that url (by refreshing the browser when the url is /heroes for example) does not direct to the corresponding component but only to the component whose path is `''` (the crisis center).

It seems to me that it should well direct to the corresponding component, but I have not managed to make it work. Or is it not the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
<base href="/">
```

to index.html. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href